# How to convert MultiLineStringZ object to MultilineString object?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I have CAD-data which I transformed to shapefiles. Currently after the transformation the objects still have a `Z value` which is useless to me.

My question is: How do I convert a `MultiLineStringZ`-object to a `MultiLineString`-object?

Answer (score 1):

There is a ST_Force2d function in PostGIS which does the job. A new table should be created with 2D geometry and use an insert statement with select to populate the new table:

```
insert into new_table (geom, col1, col2, col3) 
select ST_Force2D(geom), col1, col2, col2 from old_table;
```

You should substitute your real column names into col1, col2, ...
You can query the table structure with in psql

```
\d old_table
```

or you can use pgadmin with GUI.

Comment: Could you accept my answer clicking on the up arrow beside my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Run the `drop z values` algorithm from the QGIS processing toolbox